# Add on - rhino import not working

Tags: add-on

I am trying to install the jester king/import_3dm add-on.
However I get this error.
Anyone who might be able to help, thank you?
Best
Søren[image]

---

I add the zipped file via preferences/addon and Install button.
The add-on appears on the list but shows me this error.
I am a newbie to blender, so this does not make a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

The [add-on](https://github.com/jesterKing/import_3dm) is just a wrapper for the [`rhino3dm`](https://github.com/mcneel/rhino3dm) package, which is currently missing on your system.

The following steps should allow you to install the missing Python package:

1. Open Blender and switch to the *Scripting* workspace.
2. In the *Text Editor* press the *+ New* button.
3. Copy and paste the following script into the editor.

```
import bpy
import subprocess

try:
    output = subprocess.check_output([bpy.app.binary_path_python, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'rhino3dm'])
    print(output)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.output)
```

4. *For Blender <2.83:* Run the script by clicking on the *Run Script* button. *For Blender >=2.83:* Press the button with the play icon (triangle).
5. Enable the add-on in the preferences.

Comment: There currently seems to be a breaking API change in v0.10.0 in rhino3dm, which means that v0.9.0 of `rhino3dm` is required until `import_3dm` is updated as well.